# my docker container is not able to telnet other host application but its working in --net host mode

Tags: docker, telnet

The below code

```
    docker run --net host -dit my-apache2-2
```

is not working.

I have tried to login into the container and executed telnet to my weblogic host with port which is deployed in another host, but it failed.

However

```
    docker run -p 80:80 -dit my-apache2-2
```

is working.

Comment: docker run -p 80:80 -dit my-apache2-2 
 its not working, I think issue is host vpn isn't available in docker container